# Spring web security restrict only single page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring web security, with the below code that restricts all pages **except** those listed such as resources and app.html

How can I change this to **allow** all pages except ones I specifically specify?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration", "/app.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

I got the code from here: https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/  but I couldn't see an answer to my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/mysupersecureurl/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

This will protect your `mysupersecureurl` and let the other url be open (i.e. `permitAll()`).

Also as a bonus, you can disable csrf, if you are doing posts to other urls than the one on the `mysupersecureurl`. That is a option you can keep or remove.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `anyRequest().permitAll()` to allow all pages/apis

and `antMatchers("/api/yourAPI").authenticated()`

(or `antMatchers("/api/yourAPI").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)` for a specific user (admin here)) to restrict your pages

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration", "/app.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/yourAPI").authenticated()
                // or .antMatchers("/api/yourAPI").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```